# PWA callback on init appliaction

Tags: javascript, php, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I need catch callback when the PWA started from homescreen.

I saved every request to indexDB and when user opened the PWA from homescreen I need redirect him to last URL.

I want fix persist statement PWA for iOS.

How can I catch this callback? via serviceworker or another way?

Thank you.